# Conversion with string formatter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am using Python 2.7.6. I came across this accidentally today.

I meant to convert an integer to string through formatters. Like this:

```
a = 50
b = "%d" % (a)
```

However, I did this instead

```
a = 50
b = "%s" % (a)
```

Which also ran fine. I couldn't understand how this is happening. Is double conversion happening here?

To be precise, how `%s` accepts an integer and still do not throw any error?

Comment: Because integers have a well defined `__str__` method.

Comment: Does that mean I don't need to use `%d` for a print statement?

Comment: No, you should use `%d` only. Firstly it is going to be clear to someone who's reading your code and will also raise error if by any chance some other type of object gets passed in instead of an integer(`%s` will work for any object). Secondly things like, for example padding 0: `'%020d' % 2` and `'%020s' % 2` will return different output.

Comment: That's a great use case for `%d`. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"%s" % (a)` calls the `__str__` method of `a`.

You don't need to use `"%d" % (a)` to convert an integer to a string, just do `str(a)`

However, using `"%d" % (a)` will ensure that a is convertible to an integer e.g. `"%d" % "hello world"` will not work.

Comment: I was using it for a print statement. Otherwise, I would be using `str(a)` and wouldn't come across this scenario :-)

Comment: Is it like `"%d"%(a)` is more like `str(int(a))`?

Comment: The logic for `"%d"%(a)` is [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L4874). Short answer: if `a` is a non-long non-int number type, it tries to convert to int before rendering the final string. Non-number types are rejected without even attempting to convert.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> The conversion types are:
>   ...
>   's' | String (converts any Python object using str()).

So basically it calls `str(a)`, as horns says.